# Ambiguous error in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, class

I'm trying to make a game, and i've created a class for the Player. The class inherits "Entity", which inherits QGraphicsItem.

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include "entity.h"

class Player : public Entity
{
public:
    Player( QString, int, int, int position );

    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    void paint( QPainter *painter,
                const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                QWidget *widget );

    void move_north();
    void move_south();
    void move_west();
    void move_east();

    void start_moving();
    void stop_moving();

    void switch_step();

    bool its_moving();

    void change_pos(int);

private:
    QPoint position;
    bool is_moving;

private signals:
    void Move();
};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

But i keep getting the error "expected ':' before 'protected'", at line 33.

Answer (score 8):

```
// private signals:
signals:
```

There should be no access modifiers on `signals`, you only do that for slots.

Internal to the MOC, Qt replaces signals with its own access modifiers, which is where the protected comes from.

Answer (score 6):

[This answer has some relevant insights.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2385594/1287251) Signals are by definition `protected`, so you're code is getting converted to `private protected:`, which the compiler complains about.

In other words, you can't say `private signals:`. Just say `signals:`.