# Qt signals and slots: permissions

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, signals-slots, qt-signals

There are discrepancies between respected answers here on SO and the actual Qt docs.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143183/private-public-qt-signals) and I want some further clarification. Can anyone confirm:

- A signal is always `protected`, therefore it can be emitted only by the class or any of its subclasses. I'm not sure this is true; the question above shows answers supporting this statement. But the [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html) say: `Signals are public access functions and can be emitted from anywhere, but we recommend to only emit them from the class that defines the signal and its subclasses.` So which is it?
- Slots are just functions, and thus may be public, private or protected. Obviously an outside class *will* have the ability to control if your class connects one of its own signals to one of its own slots if the slot is public. However, again the SO information differs from the docs, which say: `a signal emitted from an instance of an arbitrary class can cause a private slot to be invoked in an instance of an unrelated class.` This means that `private` is not honored by the signal/slot mechanism?
- The words public, private, protected have no use with working with the `signal` keyword
- The emitted signal is *always* available to all other classes, that is, any other class may always connect to that signal (regardless of its permission to emit the signal).
- Despite that all signals are viewable to by all classes, you could still have two classes with signals of the same name since the `connect` function takes the class name as a signal prefix (i.e. `SomeClass::itsSignal`)

Comment: Even in Qt4 you were able to emit signal from outside of class with QMetaObject::invokeMethod

Answer (score 39, accepted):

- Signals are protected in Qt4 but are public in Qt5, thus the contradictory information.
- Slots are functions and public/protected/private is honored when calling them as such, when connecting to a signal, the metaobject system ignores it though.
- As `signals` is defined as `public:`, prepending them with e.g. private leads

to:

```
private:
public: //signals:
    void theSignal();
```

Thus it's without effect.

- All classes can be connected to any signal, correct. Signals are part of the public API in that regard.
- Having identical signal signatures is not a problem. The context is defined by the object specified as sender.

Using old-style connect:

```
Apple *apple ... Orange* orange
connect(apple, SIGNAL(changed()), this, SLOT(appleChanged()));
connect(orange, SIGNAL(changed()), this, SLOT(orangeChanged()));
```

The signal is specified as string here (without the class name in it), but as `apple` and `orange` have only one signal `changed()` each and the lookup is done in the metaobject of the QObject instance, which exists one per class (not instance), they cannot collide.

Qt 5 version with compile-time checking:

```
connect(apple, &Apple::changed, this, &MyReceiver::appleChanged);
```

Here one must specify a function, so depending on the scope, one must specify a class name (and maybe namespaces). As an ambiguous function name wouldn't be valid C++ and thus not compile, so one is safe here.

Comment: Small typo: `signals` is defined as `public` (note that there is no colon). Therefore, `private signals:` actually expands to `private public:`, not to `private: public:`.

Comment: If we take a look at the docs for te QFileSystemWatcher(https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html#fileChanged) we can find the following: `Note: This is a private signal. It can be used in signal connections but cannot be emitted by the user.`.
Are `private signals` something used just in the Qt internals or is there a possibility to have signals be private in Qt?

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at `qobjectdefs.h` (QT5.0+). In there are defined the moc macros

```
#     define signals public
```

As you can see the macros used in header files for signals are defined as public. As for the explicit statet public,private,protected directives, these are ignored in the signals section. Prior 5.0 versions of QT have signals defined as protected. Those were still available for connections using the `SIGNAL()` macro.

The slots macro

```
#     define slots
```

is defined as an empty macro and therefore can be used with:

```
public slots:
private slots:
protected slots:
```

The method visibility is used for direct method calls, so private/protected cannot be called from foreign classes directly.

Using the a `connect` statement still works independently from the visibility. This is the intended behaviour and is implemented in the moc-generated code.

If i remember correctly in earlier versions of Qt a slot was also `public` automatically, but i did not find a reference for that now.

Any other class can connect to a signal from a foreign class, as long the Q_OBJECT macro is given in the class and the foreign class is known (header included). Since signals are defined per-class it is perfectly legal to have the same signal in different classes. This is also pretty convenient, for example have a signal sendInfo(QString) in all classes makes it easier to remember. The Q_OBJECT macro makes the moc to create code needed to connect signals to slots independent to visibility.

Comment: that must have changed as I believe it used to be `define signals protected`. So this means a signal can be emitted from any other class. It is curious however why the docs indicate that a `private` slot can also be called from another class.

Comment: You can invoke the private slot from a foreign class through a connection, this is true and is afaik implemented through the Q_OBJECT macro and the 'moc' magic. But you can't call the slot directly when declared as private.

Comment: interesting, so it is valid for a foreign class to `connect` any signal to another class's `private slot`? so the word `private` only refers to the normal function call use case, while the word `slot` means the function is always `public` in a connection use case.

Comment: Yes, you can always connect to slots form foreign classes. We experienced this also in our software and we've been surprised too, but it is the intended behaviour for signal-slot connections.

Answer (score 3):

> The emitted signal is always available to all other classes, that is, any other class may always connect to that signal (regardless of its permission to emit the signal).

In Qt5, this isn't necessarily true. A signal can be defined with `QPrivateSignal` as its final argument, and in that case, only the object which declared the signal would be able to connect to it.