# labelled region in c++ class

Tags: c++, qt

I was doing Qt gui programming, in signals and slot section, I have the following syntax:

```
class Myclass
{
   public slot:

   signal:

}
```

Is this allowed to have a labelled region in class because normally I have seen this:

```
class Myclass
{
    public:
    //declarations
}
```

Can access modifiers have label also or it is a specific syntax in Qt?

Please clarify. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These labels are Qt extensions to C++ (http://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html). The MOC compiler parses the files and generates relevant glue logic. Details are in the link.

Comment: This is basically a link-only answer, which will lose almost all value if the link breaks. Can you elaborate some more (such as mentioning Qt's `#define signals protected`)?

Answer (score 0):

Qt's headers define these preprocessor macros, so that when compiling, `slot` expands to the empty string, and `signal` expands to `protected` (in Qt 4) or `public` (in Qt 5).  So as far as the C++ compiler is concerned, it sees something like:

```
class Myclass
{
   public :  /* was public slots */

   public:   /* was signals */

}
```

for your example above.

When the Meta-Object Compiler `moc` is run on the same declaration, it interprets the (un-substituted) Qt keywords, and uses them to compose meta-objects.

Comment: As explained here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129133/qt-signals-and-slots-permissions

Signals are protected in Qt4 but are public in Qt5.